# How to cast string to boolean in Clojure

Tags: string, clojure, boolean

I have following statements

```
(if "true"  (println "working") (println "not working"))
```

result is - working

```
(if "false"  (println "working") (println "not working"))
```

result is - working

Both the time result is same, How can I properly cast string to boolean in clojure.

Answer (score 15):

You can create a new java Boolean object, which has a method that accepts a string. If you then use clojure's boolean function you can actually have it work in clojure.

```
(boolean (Boolean/valueOf "true")) ;;true
(boolean (Boolean/valueOf "false")) ;;false
```

Comment: *Never do this*. Using the `Boolean` constructor is always an error, always; it shouldn't even exist. Instead, use `(Boolean/valueOf x)`.

Comment: See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html#Boolean(boolean) for one of the many explanations on the web about why you shouldn't do it. Or google for `java boolean constructor` to see a discussion. **edit** Actually the linked javadoc implies that space/speed are the reason; you're better off googling and seeing why it's semantically wrong.

Comment: So in this case it would just be for speed I assume, since it is then being cast the the clojure Boolean type? (I'm not entirely sure)

Comment: Well, since you're immediately sending the result to `clojure.core/boolean` you'll be okay, since that coerces back down to a primitive boolean (possibly with reflection). But the reason you shouldn't do it is that seeing `(Boolean. x)` in any code should set off enormous alarm bells in your head. You want to read your code without having to turn off the alarm bells every time, right? :)

Comment: Why wrap in `boolean`?  In Clojure 1.8.0, at least, `(if (Boolean/valueOf "false") :yes :no) ; => :no`, and `(identical? false (Boolean/valueOf "false")) ;=> true`.  Btw it's not just a kind of bad idea to use `(Boolean. "false")` without `boolean`; it's simply evil: `(if (Boolean. "false") :yes :no) ;=> :yes`.

Comment: @Mars The discussion in these comments is largely about an earlier version of the answer, `(Boolean. x)`. It's obsolete now, but I think worth leaving around as a PSA just in case someone writing `(Boolean. x)` happens to see this and learn why not to.

Comment: I agree.  Almost tripped me up.  I mean, `(Boolean. "false")` returns something that prints as "false".  What else could it be, but `false`?  It's true.

Comment: Is the cast to `boolean` still necessary after the update to use `boolean/valueOf`?

Comment: @nha No, you don't need to cast to `boolean`, just `(Boolean/valueOf "true")` will do.

Answer (score 12):

If you must treat strings as booleans, `read-string` is a reasonable choice. But if you know the input will be a well-formed boolean (ie, either "true" or "false"), you can just use the set `#{"true"}` as a function:

```
(def truthy? #{"true"})
(if (truthy? x)
  ...)
```

Or, if you want to treat any string but "false" as truthy (roughly how Clojure views truthiness on anything), you can use `(complement #{"false"})`:

```
(def truthy? (complement #{"false"}))
(if (truthy? x)
  ...)
```

If you want to do something as vile as PHP's weak-typing conversions, you'll have to write the rules yourself.

Comment: Why go sets way when you can just use `=`? Ex: `(def truthy? (partial = "true"))`

Comment: If you are wondering how this is working, `set` and `hash-maps` are functions and it is the same functionality as `(get #{"true" "d"} "true")` which returns the value, if it is present in the set else returns `nil`. You can read more here: http://blog.jayfields.com/2010/08/clojure-using-sets-and-maps-as.html

Comment: Why use `partial =` when you can just use a set?

Answer (score 5):

Using `read-string`

```
(if (read-string "false")  (println "working") (println "not working"))
```

Comment: This suggestion seems to work well. For ClojureScript it's `(cljs.reader/read-string ...)`.

Answer (score 3):

You should always think about wrapping code to do this kind of conversion into a clearly-named function. This enables you to be more descriptive in your code, and also allows you to change the implementation if needed at a later date (e.g. if you identify other strings that should also be counted as truthy).

I'd suggest something like:

```
(defn true-string? [s]
  (= s "true"))
```

Applying this to your test cases:

```
(if (true-string? "true")   (println "working") (println "not working"))
=> working

(if (true-string? "false")  (println "working") (println "not working"))
=> not working
```